# Tableview in JavaFX is loading data twice after adding new data in Tableview

Tags: javafx, netbeans, tableview

I'm working on an application for our warehouse. I've got a Tableview reading data form an SQL database. There's an Add button that allows to enter new products into the Tableview. 
The Tableview loads just fine when started, but when I add a new product, the product adds just fine only the Tableview loads everything again. This gives double entries in the Tableview. Looking at the Database table in DBeaver, everything is correct (no double entries there and the new product is added).

In my previous version (before using JavaFx) I would add a method to the Add functionality which allows the Tableview to refresh itself. This worked fine. Now i'm working with JavaFX and this same principle is giving me this problem.

Here's the Load Method:

```
private void LoadPickTableMethod() {
    String sql3 = "SELECT * FROM PICKLOCATIES";
    try {
        Connection con = ConnectDatabase.conDB();
        ResultSet rs = con.createStatement().executeQuery(sql3);
        while (rs.next()) {
            picklocaties.add(new TableModel(rs.getString("ID"), 
                                            rs.getString("LOCATIE"), 
                                            rs.getString("ARTIKELCODE"),
                                            rs.getString("OMSCHRIJVING"),
                                            rs.getString("EENHEID"), 
                                            rs.getString("HAL"), 
                                            rs.getString("CODE"), 
                                            rs.getString("AANTAL"),
                                            rs.getString("INITIAAL"), 
                                            rs.getString("MAX")));
        }
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(ZoekenFXMLController.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    col_id2.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("Id"));
    col_locatie2.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("Locatie"));
    col_artikelcode2.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("Artikelcode"));
    col_omschrijving2.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("Omschrijving"));
    col_eenheid2.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("Eenheid"));
    col_hal1.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("Hal"));
    col_oescode.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("Code"));
    col_initiaalP.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("Initiaal"));
    col_aantalP.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("Aantal"));
    col_max.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("Max"));
    searchTable1.setItems(picklocaties);

    col_id.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("Id"));
    col_locatie.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("Locatie"));
    col_artikelcode.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("Artikelcode"));
    col_omschrijving.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("Omschrijving"));
    col_eenheid.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("Eenheid"));
    col_hal.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("Hal"));
col_oescode1.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("Code"));
    col_initiaalP1.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("Initiaal"));
    col_aantalP1.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("Aantal"));
    col_max1.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("Max"));
    searchTable.setItems(picklocaties);


}
```

This method is called at the beginning (initialize), but also after clicking the Add button.
The Add method:

```
@FXML
private void AddPick(ActionEvent event) {
    try {
        String sql = "INSERT INTO PICKLOCATIES"
                + "(artikelcode, locatie, omschrijving, eenheid,code,hal,aantal, initiaal, max)"
                + "VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";
        conn = ConnectDatabase.conDB();
        pst = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
        pst.setString(1, autocompleteTf.getText());
        pst.setString(3, pickDescTxt.getText());
        pst.setString(2, autocompleteLoc.getText());
        pst.setString(4, pickEenheidTxt.getText());
        pst.setString(5, oesTxt.getText());
        pst.setString(6, autocompleteHal.getText());
        pst.setString(7, pickAantalTxt.getText());
        pst.setString(8, pickInitiaalTxt.getText());
        pst.setString(9, maxAantalTxt.getText());
        pst.executeUpdate();
        Alert dialog = new Alert(Alert.AlertType.INFORMATION);
        dialog.setContentText("Artikel Toegevoegd");
        dialog.setHeaderText("Informatie");
        dialog.showAndWait();

        ClearAllFields(); 
        LoadPickTableMethod();


    } catch (Exception e) {
        Logger.getLogger(LoginFXMLController.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, e);
    }

}
```

Screenshot of what happens:

[Screenshot Tableview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hf36r.png)

The last row is the newly added product (which loads only once) but the above rows are duplicates. The first 4 rows are the original ones, and the 4 below that are duplicates.

The goal is to have the Tableview update itself with the newly added product and not to duplicate itself along with it.

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated.

Edit: as per request, minimal reproducable example:

```
public class HomeFXMLController implements Initializable {
Connection conn = null;
ResultSet rs = null;
PreparedStatement pst = null;

@FXML
private TableView<TableModel> searchTable1;

@FXML
private TableColumn<TableModel, String> col_id2;

@FXML
private TableColumn<TableModel, String> col_locatie2;

@FXML
private TableColumn<TableModel, String> col_artikelcode2;

@FXML
private TableColumn<TableModel, String> col_omschrijving2;

@FXML
private TableColumn<TableModel, String> col_eenheid2;

@FXML
private TableColumn<TableModel, String> col_hal1;

@FXML
private TableColumn<TableModel, String> col_oescode;

@FXML
private TableColumn<TableModel, String> col_aantalP;

@FXML
private TableColumn<TableModel, String> col_initiaalP;

@FXML 
private TableColumn<TableModel, String> col_max;

@FXML
private JFXTextField pickEenheidTxt;

@FXML
private JFXTextArea pickDescTxt;

@FXML
private JFXTextField pickIdTxt;

@FXML
private JFXTextField oesTxt;

@FXML
private JFXButton pickAddBtn;

@FXML
private JFXTextField maxAantalTxt;

@FXML 
private JFXTextField autocompleteTf;


@FXML 
private JFXTextField autocompleteLoc;

@FXML
private JFXTextField autocompleteHal;   


ObservableList<TableModel> picklocaties = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
FilteredList filtered = new FilteredList(picklocaties, e -> true);

@Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) { 


    LoadPickTableMethod();  

@FXML //this bit is linked to pickAddBtn
    private void AddPick(ActionEvent event) {
    try {
        String sql = "INSERT INTO PICKLOCATIES"
                + "(artikelcode, locatie, omschrijving, eenheid,code,hal,aantal, initiaal, max)"
                + "VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";
        conn = ConnectDatabase.conDB();
        pst = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
        pst.setString(1, autocompleteTf.getText());
        pst.setString(3, pickDescTxt.getText());
        pst.setString(2, autocompleteLoc.getText());
        pst.setString(4, pickEenheidTxt.getText());
        pst.setString(5, oesTxt.getText());
        pst.setString(6, autocompleteHal.getText());
        pst.setString(7, pickAantalTxt.getText());
        pst.setString(8, pickInitiaalTxt.getText());
        pst.setString(9, maxAantalTxt.getText());
        pst.executeUpdate();
        Alert dialog = new Alert(Alert.AlertType.INFORMATION);
        dialog.setContentText("Artikel Toegevoegd");
        dialog.setHeaderText("Informatie");
        dialog.showAndWait();

        ClearAllFields();
        LoadPickTableMethod();


    } catch (Exception e) {
        Logger.getLogger(LoginFXMLController.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, e);
    }



    }

private void LoadPickTableMethod() {
    String sql3 = "SELECT * FROM PICKLOCATIES";
    try {
        Connection con = ConnectDatabase.conDB();
        ResultSet rs = con.createStatement().executeQuery(sql3);
        while (rs.next()) {
            picklocaties.add(new TableModel(rs.getString("ID"), 
                                            rs.getString("LOCATIE"), 
                                            rs.getString("ARTIKELCODE"),
                                            rs.getString("OMSCHRIJVING"),
                                            rs.getString("EENHEID"), 
                                            rs.getString("HAL"), 
                                            rs.getString("CODE"), 
                                            rs.getString("AANTAL"),
                                            rs.getString("INITIAAL"), 
                                            rs.getString("MAX")));
        }
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(ZoekenFXMLController.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    col_id2.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("Id"));
    col_locatie2.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("Locatie"));
    col_artikelcode2.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("Artikelcode"));
    col_omschrijving2.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("Omschrijving"));
    col_eenheid2.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("Eenheid"));
    col_hal1.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("Hal"));
    col_oescode.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("Code"));
    col_initiaalP.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("Initiaal"));
    col_aantalP.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("Aantal"));
    col_max.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("Max"));
    searchTable1.setItems(picklocaties);

    col_id.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("Id"));
    col_locatie.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("Locatie"));
    col_artikelcode.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("Artikelcode"));
    col_omschrijving.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("Omschrijving"));
    col_eenheid.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("Eenheid"));
    col_hal.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("Hal"));
    col_oescode1.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("Code"));
    col_initiaalP1.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("Initiaal"));
    col_aantalP1.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("Aantal"));
    col_max1.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("Max"));
    searchTable.setItems(picklocaties);     

    }

private void ClearAllFields() {
    autocompleteTf.setText("");
    pickDescTxt.setText("");
    pickEenheidTxt.setText("");
    autocompleteHal.setText("");
    autocompleteLoc.setText("");
    oesTxt.setText("");
    pickAantalTxt.setText("");
    pickInitiaalTxt.setText("");
    maxAantalTxt.setText("");
    }

    }
```

The Table Model:

```
package voorraadsysteem;


public class TableModel {


    public final String ID, Locatie, Artikelcode, Omschrijving, 
Eenheid, 
Hal, Code, Aantal, Initiaal, Max;

public TableModel(
        String ID, 
        String Locatie, 
        String Artikelcode, 
        String Omschrijving, 
        String Eenheid, 
        String Hal, 
        String Code, 
        String Aantal, 
        String Initiaal, 
        String Max) 
{
    this.ID = ID;
    this.Locatie = Locatie;
    this.Artikelcode = Artikelcode;
    this.Omschrijving = Omschrijving;
    this.Eenheid = Eenheid;
    this.Hal = Hal;
    this.Code = Code;
    this.Aantal = Aantal;
    this.Initiaal = Initiaal;
    this.Max = Max;
}

public String getID() {
    return ID;
}

public String getLocatie() {
    return Locatie;
}

public String getArtikelcode() {
    return Artikelcode;
}

public String getOmschrijving() {
    return Omschrijving;
}

public String getEenheid() {
    return Eenheid;
}

public String getHal() {
    return Hal;
}

public String getOescode() {
    return Code;
}

public String getAantal() {
    return Aantal;
}

public String getInitiaal() {
    return Initiaal;
}

public String getMax(){
    return Max;
}





}
```

Comment: [mcve] please .. and please learn java naming conventions and stick to them.

Comment: I've added an example in the original post. Since i'm connected to a private server at work, I won't post the database connection.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is it's because you initialize ObservableList picklocaties once when creating the class. Have you tried moving the initialization (=FXCollections.observableArrayList();) inside the AddPick method? This way an empty list will be generated everytime the method is called therefore adding the items in your DB only once.

Comment: The items get added once in the Database. The problem is that after adding the item, the TableView loads everything twice. Looking into my Database Table in Dbeaver shows no double entries. I tried your suggestion, but it doesn't seem to be doing anything. Do you suggest adding the initialization inside the try-catch block, or after?